# Recognizing Open-Math (XML) code inside textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml

```
<div id = "divTextArea" class = "formula_editor_textarea">
            <!--<textarea id= 'mathdoxformula'>
                Hello!
            </textarea>-->
            <textarea id='formula1' class='mathdoxformula' rows='10' cols='80'>
                &lt;OMOBJ xmlns='http://www.openmath.org/OpenMath'&gt;
                  &lt;OMA&gt;
                    &lt;OMS cd='arith1' name='divide'/&gt;
                    &lt;OMA&gt;
                      &lt;OMS cd='arith1' name='minus'/&gt;
                      &lt;OMA&gt;
                        &lt;OMS cd='arith1' name='power'/&gt;
                        &lt;OMV name='q'/&gt;
                        &lt;OMI&gt;2&lt;/OMI&gt;
                      &lt;/OMA&gt;
                      &lt;OMI&gt;1&lt;/OMI&gt;
                    &lt;/OMA&gt;
                    &lt;OMA&gt;
                      &lt;OMS cd='arith1' name='minus'/&gt;
                      &lt;OMV name='q'/&gt;
                      &lt;OMI&gt;1&lt;/OMI&gt;
                    &lt;/OMA&gt;
                  &lt;/OMA&gt;
                &lt;/OMOBJ&gt;

            </textarea>
        </div>
```

In the code above, I have some Open-Math code placed inside a textarea. Is there anyway in JavaScript to recognize that there is Open-Math code inside a textarea. Essentially, what I am trying to do is have a formula rendered from OpenMath and the user has the option to "Save" the formula. However, the "Save" button is disabled when there is no formula or Open-Math code inside the textarea (it doesn't make sense for a user to save a blank function/equation).

The "Save" button is enabled after the user enters a equation (the Open-Math code is updated automatically). Is there a way for JavaScript to recognize if Open-Math code is present inside the textarea so the "Save" button can be enabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use jQuery's `parseXML()` and check for a specific node.

```
contains = false;
try {
    var xml = $.parseXML(formula1.value);
    if ($(xml).find('OMOBJ').length) {
        contains = true;
    }
} catch(e) {
    console.log(e);
}
```